# on Authorization - Bearer in ionic 2 got POST 401 (Unauthorized) Error

Tags: post, ionic2

home.ts code

```
 userdetails()
 {
    // for getting token values
    this.showLoader();
    this.authService.details(this.localStoragekey).then(
        (result) => { 
            this.loading.dismiss();
            this.data = result; 
            console.log('Hello HomePage token details final',this.data);
         }, (err) => { 
            this.loading.dismiss();
            this.presentToast(err); 
        });  
 }
```

service provider code

```
details(token) 
{    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers();  
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', "Bearer" + token );  
        this.http.post(apiUrl+'details', {}, {headers: headers})  
          .subscribe(res => {resolve(res.json());           
        }, 
        (err) => { reject(err); } );
    });  
  }
```

php laravel code

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
   Route::post('details', 'API\UserController@details');
});

public function details()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this->successStatus);
}
```

php code works on postman... but when I tried using ionic 2 I got POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/details 401 (Unauthorized) error....

CORS is working fine..

thanks....

Comment: I think you miss a space after "Bearer". 

So your code would become: 
"Bearer " + token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your unauthorized error, as stated by Juxture in the comment, comes from the following line:

```
headers.append('Authorization', "Bearer" + token );
```

This implies that your Authorization header is as follows:

```
BearereyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

as opposed to the expected:

```
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

So try adding a space between Bearer and your actual token, and try it.
If you have any other problems implementing JWT I suggest you take a look at https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: You might wanna post the results of your network request using the chrome devtools. Go to the network tab and choose the correct request. Post a screenshot about that as an update to your current post.